# Not getting the right answer from an equation. Also, infinite looping

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while

Okay, so I'm supposed to calculate how much time will pass if I go at the speed of light at a certain velocity and duration. Yes, this is homework. I have it figured out for the most part, but when I enter 40 for the time and 60 for the years, I get 0.008305 when I should be getting 50. What's going on?

Also, the do while loop isn't working correctly. It repeats the whole block of code regardless of how I answer and ignores the cout and cin statements, causing it to give me errors when it evaluates v1. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

const int c = 299792458;

int main()
{
    int loopCheck = 'y';

    do
    {
        int tm = 0;

        std::cout << "Enter time of travel: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> tm;

        if (tm < 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                std::cout << "You have entered an incorrect value. " 
                          << "Please enter a value greater than 0." 
                          << std::endl;
                std::cin >> tm;

            } while (tm < 0);
        }

       double v1 = 0;

       std::cout << "Enter velocity: " << std::endl;
       std::cin >> v1;

       if (v1 <= 0 || v1 >= 100)
       {
           do
           {
               std::cout << "You have entered an incorrect value. " 
                         << "Please enter a value between 0 and 100." 
                         << std::endl;
               std::cin >> v1;

           } while (v1 <= 0 || v1 >= 100);
       }

       double v2 = (v1 / 100) * c;
       double ts = tm / (sqrt((1 - (v2 * v2))/(c * c)));

       std::cout << v2 << " " << c  << std::endl;

       std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << ts 
                 << std::endl << std::endl;

       std::cout << "Would you like to enter more data? (y/n)" << std::endl;
       std::cin >> loopCheck;
   } while (loopCheck == 'y');

   _getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: gcc gives the following warning: a.cpp:48:52: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]. It is the line `double ts = tm ... (c * c)));`

Answer (score 2):

The loop repeats always, because you enter a character `y` or `n` and `loopCheck` is declared

```
int loopCheck = 'y';
```

This means,

```
std::cin >> loopCheck;
```

looks for an integer number, but cannot find one. Depending on the version of your compiler, `loopCheck` will be unchanged or set to zero, see [`std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). If you change this to

```
char loopCheck = 'y';
```

it should work as expected.

To fix the integer overflow problem in

```
double ts = tm / (sqrt((1 - (v2 * v2))/(c * c)));
```

you could declare `c` as `double`, e.g.

```
const double c = 299792458;
```

*Update:*

There is an additional error in the formula. You have

```
sqrt((1 - v2²) / c²)
```

which gives a negative number and therefore is wrong. Removing the parenthesis

```
sqrt(1 - v2² / c²)
```

which translates to

```
double ts = tm / (sqrt(1 - (v2 * v2) / (c * c));
```

gives the correct output.

Comment: I made these changes, and they fixed the looping, but the output now says -1.#IND00. What does that mean?

Comment: Doesn't `int loopCheck = 'y'` evaluate to `int loopCheck = 121`?
And char is just an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Therefore changing to char will not alter the behaviour.

Comment: @lightandlight The problem with `int loopCheck` is not the conversion of `y` to `121`, but the `std::istream` expecting an integer. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Silly me, I didn't seem to consider that >> would be overloaded for char too

Answer (score 1):

you have some type cast error:

```
double v2 = (v1 / 100.f) * c;
double ts = tm / (sqrt((1 - (v2 * v2))/(double)(c * c)));
```

for the infinite loop, it's a other type error : change int to char.

if you use c++11, you can declare C as:

```
constexpr int c = 299792458;
```

Comment: What would constexpr do here over const?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of integer division.  If an operation first causes division of two integers, the result will be rounded down to the nearest integer.  So, for example 25/10*10 will give a result of 20.  If the result is going to be a float or a double, then it is better to convert the integer into a float or double before performing the division, eg 25/10.0*10 will be ok because the compiler will do floating point operations.

You will also have problem working in integers when the range of an intermediate result gets too large.  eg, on most systems 100000*100000/50000 won't give you the result you expect due to integer overflow.  Again, converting to a float or double first is a solution.

To debug these type of issues, try stepping through the code line by line and confirming the variables contain the values you expect, or put print the result of each operation and compare with the result from a calculator so you can narrow down where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looping problem:

`int loopCheck = 'y'` is the same as `int loopCheck = 121`, so the while loop will check for the value 121. Using `cin >> loopCheck` seems to set `loopCheck` to zero. I think this is because the arithmetic version of `operator>>` only parses digits rather than converting characters to their ascii values, so inputting non-digits returns 0.

You should call `loopCheck = cin.get()` to get the first character in the stream, and then `cin.ignore()` to discard the newline character that comes after it.

Comment: It sets `loopCheck` to zero, when you use C++11. It leaves `loopCheck` unchanged, when you have C++03 or earlier.

Comment: gnu++03 (gnu c++98) sets it to zero.

That being said, I really need to change my compiler flags.